# How to specify existing node security group in cloud formation template while creating EKS worker nodes

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, aws-cloudformation, amazon-eks

I want to create EKS worker nodes with an existing node security group in an EKS cluster.

Currently, with the following [cloudformation template](https://amazon-eks.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/cloudformation/2019-02-11/amazon-eks-nodegroup.yaml), the EKS worker node is created with a new security group.

How can I refer to the pre-existing node security group for my worker nodes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arundathi, I'm gonna use the same template to explain it.

The `NodeSecurityGroup` is being created in this template (#L200). If you want to use an existing security group then you can take it as user input, just like `ClusterControlPlaneSecurityGroup`(#L136):

```
  ClusterControlPlaneSecurityGroup:
    Description: The security group of the cluster control plane.
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup::Id
```

And, then refer to that, wherever required (#L226). For example:

```
  NodeSecurityGroupFromControlPlaneIngress:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress
    DependsOn: NodeSecurityGroup
    Properties:
      Description: Allow worker Kubelets and pods to receive communication from the cluster control plane
      GroupId: !Ref NodeSecurityGroup
      SourceSecurityGroupId: !Ref ClusterControlPlaneSecurityGroup
      IpProtocol: tcp
      FromPort: 1025
      ToPort: 65535
```

Let me know if you still have any questions.